# C++ Unordered Map With Custom Class

Tags: c++, string, dictionary, key, unordered

I'm trying to create a C++ unordered map that keys strings to one of my custom classes. i.e.:

name -> EmployeeInfo

I have used the following typedef to define the unordered map:

```
typedef std::unordered_map< std::string, class Employee > EmployeeStore;
```

But I am getting a compiler error:

```
error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Is this because the map template doesn't have a equivalency operator for type std::string? If so, can someone tell me where and how to write this. I just want a case-insensitive string key.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you included the `<string>` header? Also, you don't need to write `class`, you only need `std::unordered_map< std::string, Employee >`

Answer (score 2):

I would bet you forgot to include the string header.  That should define all the string operators.

Comment: Adding the string header fixed it. Thanks. Getting back into C++ after 10 year absence. Loving it... but it's a struggle after lots of .Net coding.